# i have a problem with my image not appearing on my canvas can you guys help me?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I am trying to make flappy bird but when I try to load the background on  my canvas it just does nothing

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

// load img 

var bird = new Image();
bird.src = "img/bird.png";
var bg = new Image();
bg.src = "img/bg.png";
var fg = new Image();
fg.src = "img/fg.png";
var pipeNoord = new Image();
pipeNoord.src = "img/pipeNorth.png";
var pipeSouth = new Image();
pipeSouth.src = "img/pipeSouth.png";

// draw images 
window.onLoad = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: It's `window.onload`. It'll probably still not work, because chances are `bg` isn't loaded yet when you attempt to draw it.

Comment: i have tried without window.onload and it still won't work

Comment: I meant it's `window.onload`, not `window.onLoad`. Capitalization matters. And it's `ctx.fillStyle`, not `ctx.fillstyle`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you move the whole image loading code into the `onload` handler. Like so, you can make sure that everything is loaded before you actually call `drawImage`. In addition, as @Chris G mentioned, it's `window.onload`, not `window.onLoad`:

```js
// draw images 
window.onload = function(){
    var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

    // load img 
    var bird = new Image();
    bird.src = "img/bird.png";
    var bg = new Image();
    bg.src = "img/bg.png";
    var fg = new Image();
    fg.src = "img/fg.png";
    var pipeNoord = new Image();
    pipeNoord.src = "img/pipeNorth.png";
    var pipeSouth = new Image();
    pipeSouth.src = "img/pipeSouth.png";
    
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: i tried with and without the window.onload  and everything in the window.onload but it still doesn't work

Comment: Hmm.. are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: no i get no errors but when i just try to draw like a rectangle with  ctx.fillstyle = "blue"; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);   it gives me the error that blue is not defined